# How to merge classes in symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

The data I have separates forests into a couple different types, and I don't like that. I want all the forest types to be together under one class called "forest".

How can I merge these classes in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: If you just need to display them all in the same way, just select Single Symbol under the symbology tab. If you need to actually have them all register as 'forest' in a field, create a new field and use the field calculator.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to change the symbology from [Unique Values](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/unique-value.htm) to [Single Symbol](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/single-symbol.htm).  You can then rename the layer to "Forests" to reflect the change in a legend and TOC.

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to *group* your classes if you want to retain the Unique Values rendering of your data. Select all the classes in the symbol panel and right click on your selection and choose Group values then edit the label to say Forest.

[image: Grouping Values]